# Gnu-Screen: Run script that sends commands to the screen session it is being run in

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Is it possible to write a script to change the name and turn on monitoring for the current tab assuming that it is being run in screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this works:

```
if [-n "$STY"]; then
    screen -X title "foo"
    screen -X monitor on
fi
```

Comment: I don't think the "if [-n..." stuff is required - the screen -X ... command silently errors if it cannot run

Comment: With this technique I think I'll forget about monitoring, I'll just change the title to foo(done) when the program finishes.  I still have to figure out when is a good time for it to change back to "bash" since I've never really used titles and don't really feel like changing them manually.

Comment: @Dan - you can use string escapes in your prompt to automagically change the title in screen.  Bash is probably a little different, but here's how I do it in zsh: http://gist.github.com/143727

Answer (score 10):

From the screen manpage:

> ```
>   -X   Send the specified command to a running screen  session.  You  can
>        use  the  -d or -r option to tell screen to look only for attached
>        or detached screen sessions. Note that this command  doesn't  work
>        if the session is password protected.
> ```

Basically, run

```
screen -X title mynewtitle
screen -X monitor on
```

If the terminal is not running within screen, it silently errors:

```
notinscreen:~$ screen -X title mynewtitle
notinscreen:~$
```

You can also send the command to a specific session, even while detached. Given a screen session named "main":

```
$ screen -S main
[detach from screen session]
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        2073.main       (Detached)
1 Socket in /tmp/uscreens/S-dbr.
```

..you can sent the title of the last-active window to `blah`:

```
$ screen -x main -X title blah
```

..or a specific window (named `oldwindow` in this example):

```
$ screen -x main -p oldwindow -X title blah
```

Instead of using `-x main` you can use the process ID (from `screen -ls`), also instead of using a window name (`-p oldwindow`) you can use a window number:

```
$ screen -x 2073 -p 0 -X title h
```

If there is only one session, you do not have to specify the session PID or name.

Answer (score 2):

Screen declares `$STY` environment variable, you can try use it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to display information or interact with the screen session itself?
You can send messages back with this: (http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html#lbAI)

> THE MESSAGE LINE
> Screen displays
> informational messages and other
> diagnostics in a message line. While
> this line is distributed to appear at
> the bottom of the screen, it can be
> defined to appear at the top of the
> screen during compilation. If your
> terminal has a status line defined in
> its termcap, screen will use this for
> displaying its messages, otherwise a
> line of the current screen will be
> temporarily overwritten and output
> will be momentarily interrupted. The
> message line is automatically removed
> after a few seconds delay, but it can
> also be removed early (on terminals
> without a status line) by beginning to
> type.
>
> The message line facility can be used
> by an application running in the
> current window by means of the ANSI
> Privacy message control sequence. For
> instance, from within the shell, try
> something like:
>
> ```
> echo '<esc>^Hello world from window '$WINDOW'<esc>\\'
> ```
>
> where '`<esc>`' is an escape, '`^`' is a
> literal up-arrow, and '`\\`' turns into
> a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Screen runs transparently, so detecting the screen session is hard.  If you try sending key presses, that would work, and would fill your terminal with a tiny bit of junk if you're not in a session.

Comment: Well, if I need to I can put something in my screenrc file like a variable declaration to make it obvious for my bash script (this script is just for me).

I'm still hung up on the other part though.  I have these programs that take several hours to run, and it'd be great if as soon as a start the program the title is renamed to the currently running process (my script is run with a single argument) and monitoring would turn on, so I could just hope to another tab and get notified when my program is done.